# Selecting XML nodes by XSL with nested for-each select

Tags: xml, xslt

We need to transform a xml message to a more readable format, so I tried to add some XSL.
I'm having difficulties to list everything the way I want it.

I'm rather new to XSL so some help would be appriciated.

this a part of the XML file:

```
<biotronik-ieee11073-export format-version="3.0" creator="BioProgrammerConverter" creator-version="3.1">
<dataset>
    <section name="MDC">
        <section name="ATTR">
            <section name="PT">
                <value name="SEX" type="String">0</value>
            </section>
        </section>
        <section name="IDC">
            <section name="PG">
                <value name="TYPE" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_PG_TYPE">IPG</value>
                <value name="MODEL" type="String">Evia DR-T</value>
                <value name="SERIAL" type="String">xxxxxxxx</value>
                <value name="MFG" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_MFG">BIO</value>
                <value name="IMPLANT_DT" type="DateTime">20091126</value>
            </section>
            <section name="LEAD">
                <value name="MODEL" type="String">4524</value>
                <value name="MFG" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_MFG">MDT</value>
                <value name="POLARITY_TYPE" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_LEAD_POLARITY_TYPE">BI</value>
                <value name="LOCATION" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_LEAD_LOCATION_CHAMBER">RA</value>
                <value name="CONNECTION_STATUS" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_LEAD_STATUS">Connected</value>
            </section>
            <section name="LEAD">
                <value name="MODEL" type="String">T 44 F</value>
                <value name="MFG" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_MFG">ELA</value>
                <value name="POLARITY_TYPE" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_LEAD_POLARITY_TYPE">BI</value>
                <value name="LOCATION" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_LEAD_LOCATION_CHAMBER">RV</value>
                <value name="CONNECTION_STATUS" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_LEAD_STATUS">Connected</value>
            </section>
```

In some way I want to show all  tags under node  = IDC

I tried with the follow XSL :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>Biotronics Results</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
<th>Test</th>
<th>Value</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="/biotronik-ieee11073-export/dataset/section[@name='MDC']/section[@name='IDC']">
<xsl:for-each select="section">
<xsl:for-each select="value">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="value"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You want**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="//section[@name='IDC']//value"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<biotronik-ieee11073-export format-version="3.0" creator="BioProgrammerConverter" creator-version="3.1">
    <dataset>
        <section name="MDC">
            <section name="ATTR">
                <section name="PT">
                    <value name="SEX" type="String">0</value>
                </section>
            </section>
            <section name="IDC">
                <section name="PG">
                    <value name="TYPE" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_PG_TYPE">IPG</value>
                    <value name="MODEL" type="String">Evia DR-T</value>
                    <value name="SERIAL" type="String">xxxxxxxx</value>
                    <value name="MFG" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_MFG">BIO</value>
                    <value name="IMPLANT_DT" type="DateTime">20091126</value>
                </section>
                <section name="LEAD">
                    <value name="MODEL" type="String">4524</value>
                    <value name="MFG" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_MFG">MDT</value>
                    <value name="POLARITY_TYPE" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_LEAD_POLARITY_TYPE">BI</value>
                    <value name="LOCATION" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_LEAD_LOCATION_CHAMBER">RA</value>
                    <value name="CONNECTION_STATUS" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_LEAD_STATUS">Connected</value>
                </section>
                <section name="LEAD">
                    <value name="MODEL" type="String">T 44 F</value>
                    <value name="MFG" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_MFG">ELA</value>
                    <value name="POLARITY_TYPE" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_LEAD_POLARITY_TYPE">BI</value>
                    <value name="LOCATION" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_LEAD_LOCATION_CHAMBER">RV</value>
                    <value name="CONNECTION_STATUS" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_LEAD_STATUS">Connected</value>
                </section>
            </section>
        </section>
    </dataset>
</biotronik-ieee11073-export>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<value name="TYPE" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_PG_TYPE">IPG</value>
<value name="MODEL" type="String">Evia DR-T</value>
<value name="SERIAL" type="String">xxxxxxxx</value>
<value name="MFG" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_MFG">BIO</value>
<value name="IMPLANT_DT" type="DateTime">20091126</value>
<value name="MODEL" type="String">4524</value>
<value name="MFG" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_MFG">MDT</value>
<value name="POLARITY_TYPE" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_LEAD_POLARITY_TYPE">BI</value>
<value name="LOCATION" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_LEAD_LOCATION_CHAMBER">RA</value>
<value name="CONNECTION_STATUS" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_LEAD_STATUS">Connected</value>
<value name="MODEL" type="String">T 44 F</value>
<value name="MFG" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_MFG">ELA</value>
<value name="POLARITY_TYPE" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_LEAD_POLARITY_TYPE">BI</value>
<value name="LOCATION" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_LEAD_LOCATION_CHAMBER">RV</value>
<value name="CONNECTION_STATUS" type="MDC_IDC_ENUM_LEAD_STATUS">Connected</value>
```

Comment: yes getting very close, but I want the <value name> tags to show their attributes in a 2 column table...How can I do that?

Comment: @user1292411: By asking a new, separate SO question. Your current question is completely answered -- therefore it is appropriate for you to *accept* this answer  -- by clicking the check-mark next to the answer.